# Android show notification from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, wifi, broadcastreceiver

I have a class which extends BroadcastReceiver that gets called whenever new Wifi scan results are available (the receiver is registered in the manifest with the Scan_Results broadcast as the intent-filter).

From this class, I want to be able to show a notification to the user. Currently, I pass the context that is received as a parameter in the onReceive method of my broadcast intent class to a "show notification" method of another class.

When it gets to the line:

```
myNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

it fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentView required: pkg=com.mumfordmedia.trackify id=2131034122 notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0)
```

Any idea why this is happening? All I can think of is because the context that I am getting from the onReceive parameter is not ... for lack of a better phrase, "right for the job"...

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Max.

Comment: Perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826786/pendingintents-in-notifications will help. Anyway, show us more code so we can help.

Comment: Please show us some more of your code so we can get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: By the way, Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you a response is helpful, pleas up vote it. If the response successfully answers you question please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 13):

ContentView is the view which is required when the notification is clicked. The code below works fine and `setLatestEventInfo()` is required method.

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            "Hello from service", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "contentTitle", "contentText",
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0));
    manager.notify(111, notification);
```

Comment: +1: using setLatestEventInfo() causes the error to go away. It's a little annoying how many lines of code it takes to get such a simple notification displayed...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly why it wasnt working before but here is the code I got it working with:

Declare the following outside of any method:

```
int YOURAPP_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1234567890;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
```

Then in the onReceive method call the following:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
showNotification(context, R.drawable.icon, "short", false);
```

Then declare the following method:

```
private void showNotification(Context context, int statusBarIconID, String string, boolean showIconOnly) {
        // This is who should be launched if the user selects our notification.
        Intent contentIntent = new Intent();

        // choose the ticker text
        String tickerText = "ticket text";

        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "ticker text", System.currentTimeMillis());

        PendingIntent appIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, contentIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, "1", "2", appIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(YOURAPP_NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call Notification.setLatestEventInfo().

Answer (score 1):

Use this code along with your notification

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicDroid.class);
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "This is the title", 
    "This is the text", activity);
notification.number += 1;

nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, when you're creating you notification to pass to the Notification manager, you're not giving it a content view to display. Review the line where you actually create the notification to see if you're actually giving the notification a view to display.

Comment: I copied and pasted the notification script from elsewhere in the app where it does work. There is no content view available because it is being activated from a class that extends a BroadcastReceiver which has no layout. Why does it need a content view? I will review the documentation in a few hours... thanks for the reply btw

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using NotificationCompat, the following code will work:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentText("Notify Title").setContentText("Sample Text");
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent ac = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
    n.setContentIntent(ac);
    nm.notify(12222, n.build());
```